# How to distinguish argument parentheses and grouping parentheses?

Tags: notation

$$s(a+b)$$

Does it mean s times a+b, or is s a funtion and take a+b as arguments?

$$(s(a+b))(c+d)$$

Does it mean s(a+b) times (c+d), or is s a high order function and s(a+b) return a function which then take c+d as arguments?

As a reader, how do I distinguish these cases?

As a writer, how can I make my formula super clear when it's needed?

I don't believe I'm the first one who find them confusing. I expect to see references/literatures. Thanks.

Comment: Generally, if $s$ is a function then it would be defined before-hand. Also, only the bracket after the function is considered.

Answer (score 2):

The notation for the different things you mention are completely identical, and yes, without context it is certainly ambiguous.

However, such expressions (should) never exist in a vacuum. Before (or possibly immediately after) such an expression is written, it should be made clear whether $s$ is a function or a number (and it should also be made clear what $a$ and $b$ are). And with such a clarification, the expression is no longer ambiguous.

That being said, $(a+b)s$ is less prone to being misunderstood, as most mathematicians apply functions to whatever is to the right, not to the left.